# Ender 3 V2 upgrades and addons

Tags: creality-ender-3

I am very new to 3D printing. I am looking to purchase the Ender 3 V2 but before I do I would appreciate some advice on what I should purchase as the upgrades/addons for it. I'm not sure as to what I would need for the V2 since most websites are for the original Ender 3 so I don't know if the V2 already has that upgrade/addons or not when compared to the original. I would rather get all the upgrades/addons and the Ender 3 V2 at the same to save on shipping and all.

Pretty much the only upgrade/addons I have constantly seen is the auto bed level.

So if anyone can help out a first time 3D printer noob then that would be great!

Comment: Automatic bed leveling (ABL) is not necessary as in "a must", for many it is considered to be the Holy Grail, but a flat bed and manual leveling will work fine. Note that for ABL you need to provide a bed as level as possible, the ABL will take care of large deflections that cannot be leveled out e.g.a large concave or convex area. Good luck printing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also been looking at getting into 3D printing and purchasing the Ender-3 V2.

In my research, the biggest differences between the original and V2 are the following:

- Tempered carborundum glass bed
- HD color screen instead of the old LCD character display
- Upgraded, 32-bit, self-developed, “silent” motherboard
- Capability to resume a print after a power outage
- XY-axis tensioner
- Manual filament feeding
- Toolbox embedded in the base of the printer

For more info, you can see more at all3dp and Creality's sites.
Next, there are several YouTube vids on upgrades/add-ons that you can do:

- [Firmware upgrade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxfJelrckjM)
- [Dual Gear Extruder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5gbFe7tjZQ)
- [Bed Springs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8Ku8vZD9_g)
- [Another Bed Glass upgrade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hov9lfBqXIw)
- [Octoprint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OP2c-GQFu4)

There are several add-ons you can print yourself once you get your printer (some are not specific to the Ender 3 V2). Of course, you will have to decide which of these you are looking to add. Here are just a few:

- [First 24 Upgrades on my Ender 3 Pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kG_YKeJDaX8&t=447s)
- [Ender 3 Pro Upgrades](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oy1wiP6dPjg)
- [Ender 3 Upgrades](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrLvz7OGAe4)

I would suggest, as others have, get the printer first and take it for a "test drive" first. Once you have seen its capabilities and if, again IF, anything needs to be fixed/upgraded/updated, then do what your budget allows. And by all means, do extensive research, ask questions on forums and here, and most of all have fun!

(Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to create more links.)

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, it's probably better to get the printer as-is first. This way you can get familiar with the printer and 3D printing in general before you get overwhelmed with all the extra introduced variables from your upgrades.

The new model already has loads of features that were considered upgrades on the older model and you can already get very nice results.

Upgrading your printer is a part of the 3D printing hobby, and you'll probably never be done with it :)

Answer (score 2):

The first things I purchased for my V2 within the first week of having it were the magnetic flexible print bed as the prints were a pain in the butt to remove from the glass, and the aluminum extruder upgrade. I didn't do the dual gear drive because honestly I didn't pay attention at the time. however, the aluminum  set is more positive in feel when feeding compared to the plastic that comes stock. I just felt like I'd break the arm if I tried harder than I should whereas having the aluminum arm feels better to me. Beyond that, maybe the BLTouch leveling sensor so you can set everything right more easily than using a piece of paper, but that's really all I can suggest for now. I've been using mine quite a bit lately and have enjoyed it as is. I realize this post is over a couple months old, but I just saw it and thought I'd contribute if you haven't already made your purchase(s).

Comment: My guy downgraded from the tempered glass to that awful magnetic bed lmao should have just bought and ender 3 or ender 3 pro...tempered glass bed is one of the best upgrades on the v2

Answer (score 0):

I have an Ender 3 v2 and I haven't upgraded anything except updating the firmware. The first thing I suggest is updating the firmware and changing the hotend to an all-metal one. This will allow you to print in higher temperatures and adding a BLTouch for automatic bed leveling will make your life a bit easier.

Comment: An all-metal hotend is not an upgrade if you're using ABS, PETG or PLA (basically printing under 250 °C), it is a wide accepted mistake that gives many people headaches as such hotends are much more susceptible to clog due to heat creep issues.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the approach of using the V2 as is. Review some of the YouTube videos on initial setup and calibration.  Identify the type of printing you'll doing and identify where it's coming up short of expectations. That will be the driver of what upgrades you'll want to start with.

Upgrades I've done to date:

BLTouch
Bed Springs (should have gone with spacers with the BLTouch)
Borosilicate glass print bed (OEM tempered glass bed was cupped in the middle)
Bowden tube (Lower friction)
X-axis belt (original shredded)
All fans for added reliability
Filament guide

Between the calibration and the above updates, I'm consistently printing dimensionally accurate parts.  But your situation may vary as quality and tolerances in economy parts varies.  Highly recommend the V2 though as the out of the box prints were far better than draft quality.

Answer (score 0):

As per my information, you don't need to upgrade your 3D printer but some of the following steps keep in mind to have your Ender 3 print better:

1. Level the bed.
2. Set the nozzle height.
3. Try different Build Plates for different effects.
4. Keep it on the sweet spot for your bed temperature.
5. Printer adjustment and maintenance are kept on priority.